# Vue JS Array Formatting

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I am having a terrible time wrapping my head around arrays for Vue JS.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: `
        <div class="cascading-dropdown">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <span>Cereal:</span>
                <select v-model="cerealname">
                    <option value="">SELECT A CEREAL</option>
                    <option v-for="(addon1_obj, addon1) in cereals" :value="addon1">{{addon1}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <span>Addon 1:</span>
                <select :disabled="addons1.length == 0" v-model="addon1">
                    <option value="">Select Addon 1</option>
                    <option v-for="(addon2_obj, addon2) in addons1">{{addon2}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <span>Addon 2:</span>
                <select :disabled="addons2.length == 0" v-model="addon2">
                    <option value="">Select Addon 2</option>
                    <option v-for="addon2 in addons2">{{addon2}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <span>Addon 3:</span>
                <select :disabled="addons2.length == 0" v-model="addon3">
                    <option value="">Select Addon 3</option>
                    <option v-for="addon2 in addons2">{{addon2}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div>Addon 1 text <input id="addon1desc" type="text" v-midel="addon1desc"></div>
            <div>Addon 2 text <input id="addon2desc" type="text" v-midel="addon2desc"></div>
            <div>Addon 3 text <input id="addon3desc" type="text" v-midel="addon3desc"></div>
        </div>
    `,
  data: function() {
    return {
      cereals: {
        "Lucky Charms": {
          "Marshmallows": ["Green Clovers",
            "Pink Hearts",
            "Yellow Moons",
            "Blue Diamonds",
            "Purple Horseshoes"
          ]
        },
        "Froot Loops": {
          "Loops": ["Red Loop",
            "Green Loop",
            "Blue Loop",
            "Yellow Loop"
          ]
        }
      },
      addons1: [],
      addons2: [],
      cerealname: "",
      addon1: "",
      addon2: "",
      addon3: ""
    }
  },
  watch: {
    cerealname: function() {
      // Clear previously selected values
      this.addons1 = [];
      this.addons2 = [];
      this.addon1 = "";
      this.addon2 = "";
      this.addon3 = "";
      // Populate list of countries in the second dropdown
      if (this.cerealname.length > 0) {
        this.addons1 = this.cereals[this.cerealname]
      }
    },
    addon1: function() {
      // Clear previously selected values
      this.addons2 = [];
      this.addon2 = "";
      this.addon3 = "";
      // Now we have a continent and country. Populate list of cities in the third dropdown
      if (this.addon1.length > 0) {
        this.addons2 = this.cereals[this.cerealname][this.addon1]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.dropdown {
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;
}

.dropdown span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.1/vue.js"></script>
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4zfh80au/

When you select Lucky Charms in the first dropdown, the 2nd dropdown changes to Marshmallows.  The 3rd and 4th dropdowns change to the individual marshmallow types.

What I want is to add data to the text boxes based on the dropdown selection.  When you choose the 2nd dropdown to be Marshmallows, I want the corresponding text box to fill in some text like "Marshmallows are yummy."  The 3rd and 4th dropdowns should do the same.

Could anyone please point me in the right direction??  Much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please share what you've tried so far?

Comment: What exactly is `v-midel` supposed to be? Is that a new binding I've missed? Or is that just a careless typo and should be `v-model` instead? About the rest, the vue error messages clearly tell you what you're failing at.

Comment: I'm not even sure how to format it to work.  I found the current solution on a fiddle and made it work for me.  I'm lost on how to add another option.

Answer (score 0):

The binding is already set up in each of your `<select>` tags with `v-model="addon1"`, `addon2`, and `addon3`.

In your `<div>`, have the bindings in the text fields match the ones defined in your `<select>` tags like so:

```
...
        <div class="dropdown">
            <span>Addon 1:</span>
            <select :disabled="addons1.length == 0" v-model="addon1">
                <option value="">Select Addon 1</option>
                <option v-for="(addon2_obj, addon2) in addons1">{{addon2}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <span>Addon 2:</span>
            <select :disabled="addons2.length == 0" v-model="addon2">
                <option value="">Select Addon 2</option>
                <option v-for="addon2 in addons2">{{addon2}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <span>Addon 3:</span>
            <select :disabled="addons2.length == 0" v-model="addon3">
                <option value="">Select Addon 3</option>
                <option v-for="addon2 in addons2">{{addon2}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div>Addon 1 text <input id="addon1desc" type="text" v-model="addon1"></div>
        <div>Addon 2 text <input id="addon2desc" type="text" v-model="addon2"></div>
        <div>Addon 3 text <input id="addon3desc" type="text" v-model="addon3"></div>
    </div>
...
```

You can check out [the working fiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/4zfh80au/3/)

Additionally, the fiddle link that you shared had a typo in `v-model`. If you run the app, you should see an error thrown into the console that says something like this:

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve directive: midel 
(found in anonymous component - use the "name" option for better debugging messages.)
```

If something in the app is failing, you can use the console to better debug your code.

Comment: This works if I wanted to use the Addon text.  I wanted to use a different text string for the addon description boxes.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wanting the solution, the Fiddle is here:
https://jsfiddle.net/q1jm0ccf/

The array looks as follows:

```
data: function() {
    return {
      cereals: {
        "Lucky Charms": {
          "Marshmallows": [
            {"title": "Green Clovers", "value": "The Green Clovers is nice"},
            {"title":"Pink Hearts", "value": "The Pink Hearts is cool"},
            {"title":"Yellow Moons", "value": "The Yellow Moons is best"},
            {"title":"Blue Diamonds","value": "The Blue Diamonds is bad"},
            {"title":"Purple Horseshoes","value": "The Purple Horseshoes is normal"},
            {"title":"Red","value": "The red ones are great."},
            {"title":"Yellow","value": "The yellow ones are better"}
          ]
        },
        "Froot Loops": {
          "Loops": [
          {"title":"Red","value": "Red loops are cherry"},
          {"title":"Green","value": "Green loops are lime"}
          ]
        }
      },
```